# How to Remove the Readonly attribute of a File MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

In my MFC application I have set the read only attribute on a particular file.
I have done this by using the `SetFileAttributes()` function.
At some point I have to remove that attribute of that file again.

Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: Don't you just GetFileAttributes, mask off the flag (flags &=~READ_ONLY) and SetFileAttributes again?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `SetFileAttributes` again to reset the flag:

```
SetFileAttributes( pszFilename,  
                   GetFileAttributes(pszFilename) & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);
```

---

Might be worth adding that this method returns `0` if the function fails and you can use `GetLastError()`.

Comment: GetFileAttributes() may returned many other flags that the SetFileAttributes() function doesn't understand, is that safe? Will those extra flag be ignored?