# .NET File Access Violation

Tags: c#, .net

I feel kind of stupid posting this, but it seems like a genuine issue that I've made sufficiently simple so as to demonstrate that it should not fail. As part of my work I am responsible for maintaining build systems that take files under version control, and copy them to other locations. Sounds simple, but I've constantly experienced file access violations when attempting to copy files that I've supposedly already set as 'Normal'.

The code sample below simply creates a set of test files, makes them read only, and then copies them over to another folder. If the files already exist in the destination folder, the RO attribute is cleared so that the file copy will not fail.

The code works to a point, but at seemingly random points an exception is thrown when the file copy is attempted. The code is all single threaded, so unless .NET is doing something under the hood that causes a delay on the setting of attributes I can't really explain the problem.

If anyone can explain why this is happening I'd be interested. I'm not looking for a solution unless there is something I am definitely doing wrong, as I've handled the issue already, I'm just curious as no one else seems to have reported anything related to this.

After a few iterations I get something like:

A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\TempFolderB\TEMPFILENAME8903.txt' is denied.

One other fact, if you get the file attributes BEFORE the file copy, the resulting state says the file attributes indeed Normal, yet examination of the local file shows it as Read Only.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Test copying multiple files from one folder to another while resetting RO attr
    /// </summary>
    static void MultiFileCopyTest()
    {
        /// Temp folders for our test files
        string folderA = @"C:\TempFolderA";
        string folderB = @"C:\TempFolderB";

        /// Number of files to create
        const int fileCount = 10000;

        /// If the test folders do not exist populate them with some test files
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderA) == false)
        {
            const int bufferSize = 32768;

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderA);
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderB);

            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            /// Create a bunch of files and make them all Read Only
            for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
            {
                string filename = folderA + "\\" + "TEMPFILENAME" + i.ToString() + ".txt";

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename) == false)
                {
                    System.IO.FileStream str = System.IO.File.Create(filename);
                    str.Write(tempBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    str.Close();
                }

                /// Ensure files are Read Only
                System.IO.File.SetAttributes(filename, System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
            }
        }

        /// Number of iterations around the folders
        const int maxIterations = 100;

        for (int idx = 0; idx < maxIterations; idx++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Iteration {0}", idx);

            /// Loop for copying all files after resetting the RO attribute
            for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
            {
                string filenameA = folderA + "\\" + "TEMPFILENAME" + i.ToString() + ".txt";
                string filenameB = folderB + "\\" + "TEMPFILENAME" + i.ToString() + ".txt";

                try
                {

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filenameB) == true)
                    {
                        System.IO.File.SetAttributes(filenameB, System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal);
                    }

                    System.IO.File.Copy(filenameA, filenameB, true);
                }
                catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check the count of files in the folder? Depending on your file system type, there are limits: http://superuser.com/questions/16207/how-many-files-can-a-windows-folder-contain

Comment: The same issue is found with any number of files, small or large, and randomly, the first few iterations are often fine. My tests have shown around 23 failures per 1,000,000 files.

Comment: Virus scanner running?

Comment: Tried with all AV / backup SW disabled, also tried on multiple PC's, all show the exact same result.

Comment: I've noticed this as well, I'd definitely be curious to hear some thoughts. I've ended up using native CopyFile instead in a few projects, which hasn't given me any problems.

Comment: Do you get the error if you remove the SetAttributes call?

Comment: If you remove the SetAttributes call the exception is thrown for every single file as they are intentionally set to Read Only.

Answer (score 2):

(This isn't a full answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet to post comments...)

I don't think you are doing anything wrong, when I run your test code I can reproduce the problem every time. I have never got past 10 iterations without the error occurring.

I did a further test, which might shed some light on the issue:

I set all of the files in TempFolderA to hidden.

I then ensured all of the files in TempFolderB were NOT hidden.

I put a break-point on `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)`

I ran the code, if it got past iteration 1 then I stopped, reset the hidden attributes and ran again.

After a couple of tries, I got a failure in the 1st iteration so I opened Windows Explorer on TempFolderB and scrolled down to the problematic file.

The file was 0 bytes in size, but had RHA attributes set.

Unfortunately I have no idea why this is. Process Monitor doesn't show any other activity which could be relevant.

Comment: Those results match with my own, when it fails examining the file in question it appears as zero bytes and is read only, yet according to the file status if read immediately before the copy operation comes back as Normal. I guess this a bug somewhere in .NET or a lower level, I'm just surprised something so obvious has not been resolved, as it's caused me some headaches for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, right in the documentation for the [`System.IO.File.SetAttributes(string path, System.IO.FileAttributes attributes)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) method, I found the following:

> **Exceptions:**
>   `System.UnauthorizedException`: 
>   
>    `path` specified a file that is read-only. 
>   
>    **-or-** This operation is not supported on the current platform.
>   
>    **-or-** The caller does not have the required permission.

So, if I had to guess, the file in the destination (e.g. `filenameB`) did in fact already exist. It was marked Read-Only, and so, the exception was thrown as per the documentation above.

Instead, what you need to do is remove the Read-Only attribute via an inverse bit mask:

```
if (FileExists(filenameB))
{
    // Remove the read-only attribute
    FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(filenameB);
    attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
    File.SetAttributes(filenameB, attributes);

    // You can't OR the Normal attribute with other attributes--see MSDN.
    File.SetAttributes(filenameB, FileAttributes.Normal);
}
```

To be fair, the documentation on the `SetAttributes` method isn't real clear about how to go about setting file attributes once a file is marked as `Readonly`. Sure, there's an example (using the `Hidden` attribute), but they don't explicitly say that you need to use an inverted bitmask to remove the `Hidden` or `Readonly` attributes. One could easily assume it's just how they chose to "unset" the attribute. It's also not clear from the documentation about what would happen, for instance, if you marked the file thusly:

```
File.SetAttributes(pathToFile, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.SetAttributes(pathToFile, FileAttributes.Archived);
```

Does this result in the file first having `Normal` attributes set, then *only* `Archived`, or does it result in the file having `Normal` set, and then _additionally`having`Archived` set, resulting in a Normal, but Archived file? I believe it's the former, rather than the latter, based on how attributes are "removed" from a file using the inverted bitmask.

If anyone finds anything contrary, please post a comment and I'll update my answer accordingly.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the attempted explanation. Unfortuately it doesn't have any effect on the issue, if there was such a howler of a problem, it would affect more than 23 out of 1,000,000 files. The setting and clearing of the bit fields in the file attributes is very clear and straight fwd. Setting to Normal will simply clear all other bits. Your example needs changing to read:

attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

I had my code setup to mask the RO bit originally, but changed it to use Normal to make the example easier to understand / read.

Comment: Setting to Normal will not clear all other bits. It will add the "normal" bits to the existing bits. And, since the file has `ReadOnly` as part of its bits, the file is readonly, and so you are unable to add the `Normal` bits to the file security. You first need to remove the `ReadOnly` bit via the inverse bitbmask and then set the `Normal` bits, per the MSDN documentation referenced.

Comment: @mindeater You are right about the `&=` vs. `|=`. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @mindeater Perhaps its the way the `ReadOnly` bit is being set. In the MSDN documentation, the set the `Hidden` flag thusly (and the `ReadOnly` one would work the same way): `File.SetAttributes(filenameB, File.GetAttributes(filenameB) | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);`. I updated my code sample accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're basing this information on, call me old school, but I've just verified that setting the attribute to Normal does indeed remove all other attributes. It simply has to, the attributes are simply using bit values.
TEST CODE:

   System.IO.File.SetAttributes(testFilename, System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly | System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden | System.IO.FileAttributes.Offline);
   System.IO.File.SetAttributes(testFilename, System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal);

Comment: @mindeater Hmm, the MSDN documentation clearly says that if you call `SetAttributes` on a file that is `ReadOnly`, the `UnauthorizedException` will be thrown (unless you're removing the `ReadOnly` bit via `~FileAttributes.ReadOnly` bitmask). The same should happen if `Hidden` is set. If those two attributes are not set, then you can set attributes willy-nilly.

Comment: Indeed, BUT if a file is ReadOnly, the attribute is 0x1. If you call SetAttributes with Normal (128), this inherently clears bit 0, so clearing the RO bit. I think you're getting caught up in the syntax of the examples, bottom line is we're simply changing the attributes to a value of 128, which means Normal, no attributes set, and so should not cause any file access violations.

Comment: The `SetAttributes` method internally calls the Win32 API function `SetFileAttributes`. [Here's another SO question with an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913927/how-to-remove-the-readonly-attribute-of-a-file-mfc) that shows clearing the read-only bit on a file--which is exactly what I've done in my example above.

Comment: @mindeater I also fixed my sample. The MSDN documentation states that `FileAttributes.Normal` cannot be combined with anything else, yet, I combined it with the original file's attributes (the Win32 API documentation states the same--it can't be combined with anything else). I've udpated my example accordingly. Perhaps this is  why the sample code wasn't working.

Comment: Unfortunately as I said, none of this is relevant to the problem in hand. Regardless of how you choose to manipulate the file attributes, the code works as expected 'most' of the time, then seemingly randomly fails usually after a number of successful iterations. If there were some flaw in the attributes handling in the application code, it would fail for every single file, this is clearly not the case. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

This may cause because user don't have sufficient permission to access file system ,

work around :

1,Try to run application in administrative mode

OR

2,Try to run visual studio in administrative mode (if you are using debugger)

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear, the error appears randomly, usually after a number of successful iterations over the 10,000 files in the example code, and fails on all pc's I've tested it on. It's not a local issue to me, it appears to be a bug in .NET (or a lower level), if it was a permission issue, it would fail on the first file, not on file access 40,456.